# Why is Pyppeteer not working for getting HTML "generated" by Solid.js?

Tags: python, html, web, pyppeteer, solid-js

I am trying to get the hole content of a website, which is using Solid.js. But I am not able to get the content "generated" by Solid.js.

Until now I tried:

```
from pyppeteer import launch

async def main():
    browser = await launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto("https://examplewebsiteusingsolidjs.com/")
    root = await page.evaluate('document.body.innerHTML')
    await browser.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

But this does not work.
My Output: `<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript> <div id="root" style="overflow: initial"></div>`
How can I change the code, so that I also get the content generated by Solid.js (which is inside the div with the id="root"?

Comment: `await page.evaluate('#root')`? I doubt you want the whole app content though--you probably want something specific in there. So it's good to say what, and show the HTML so others can help you get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you did not enable javascript. Insert this code after creating new page:

```js
await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: that does not work